# ora-12505 error while starting new connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I got this error while starting new connection in Oracle 11g:

> Listern refused the connection with the follwoing error: ORA-12505,TNS: Listner does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
>   the connection descriptor used by the client was: localhost:1521:xe

What is the SID and how can I fix the error?

Comment: Do you have access to the Oracle server or are you doing this from a client?

Answer (score 1):

The SID in this case is XE (think of the SID being the database name).  The Error means that the listener is not configured to listen for a database called XE on port 1521 on server localhost.  Unless you are running the client and server on the same box localhost isn't likely to be correct - change this to the server name.  This looks like a connection to Oracle XE which isn't available for 11g (yet) so it isn't clear what your set-up is exactly and so it is difficult to provide a definitive answer - but most likely wither the database is down or you are connecting to the wrong server.